# Why I face Fatal Error in mysql with nodejs?

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, fatal-error

I`m trying to create a database with mysql module in nodejs but after I create a table and insert some data, when I try to SELECT and get results back, I face fatal error!!

```
    D:\Programming\Farahani App\App>node mysql.js
    Error: Cannot enqueue Query after fatal error.
        at Protocol._validateEnqueue (D:\Programming\Farahani App\App\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:212:16)
        at Protocol._enqueue (D:\Programming\Farahani App\App\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:138:13)
        at Connection.query (D:\Programming\Farahani App\App\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:198:25)
        at Handshake.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\Farahani App\App\mysql.js:28:13)
        at Handshake.<anonymous> (D:\Programming\Farahani App\App\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:526:10)
        at Handshake._callback (D:\Programming\Farahani App\App\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:488:16)
        at Handshake.Sequence.end (D:\Programming\Farahani App\App\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:83:24)
        at Protocol.handleNetworkError (D:\Programming\Farahani App\App\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\Protocol.js:369:14)
        at Connection._handleNetworkError (D:\Programming\Farahani App\App\node_modules\mysql\lib\Connection.js:418:18)
        at Socket.emit (node:events:390:28) {
      code: 'PROTOCOL_ENQUEUE_AFTER_FATAL_ERROR',
      fatal: false
    }
    undefined
```

[mysql is running in my xampp if related... ]

appreciate your help.

my code:

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const data = {
    host: "localhost",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "mydb"
}
const con = mysql.createConnection(data)

    con.connect(() => {


        // create database 
        con.query('CREATE DATABASE mydb', () => {

        })
        // create table
        const table = "CREATE TABLE customers (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))";
        con.query(table, () => {
            })
        // add val to table
        const val1 = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('Company Inc', 'Highway 37')";
        con.query(val1, () => {

        })
        // log results
        con.query("SELECT * FROM customers",  (err,result)=>{
            if(err) {console.log(err)};
            console.log(result);
        })
        con.end();
    })
```

Comment: as `con.query` is async, but you are not awaiting the query results, you are executing multiple queries in parallel.  Especially, you are not awaiting the creation of your database before creating your `customers` table. And you are not awaitng the creation of your table before inserting and reading from it.

Comment: And probably, after creating a new database, you will need to update the scope of your connection to this database.

Comment: derpirscher, OP is using callback chains to handle async. The formatting is a little off so it's hard to see. ali-babaee, you may want to convert your code to use promises and async / await to make things easier to understand.

Comment: @kevintechie Yes, he is using callbacks. But still, all the `con.query("..", () => {})` are on the same nesting level. Ie, executing the `CREATE TABLE` query doesn't happen *within*  the callback of `CREATE DATABASE` but *outside*  of it. Thus, this piece of code won't wait for the callback to be executed before executing the next `con.query(...)`. All `con.query()` are nested in the callback of `con.connect()` though ... The formatting is perfectly fine and exactly fitting to the nesting levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with your code. The main problem is that you cannot do multiple queries per connection in mysql.

You can use [connection pools](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections) to make this easier to manage.

Second, you should check for errors in the callback. This will help in debugging as well as making your code more robust.

```
con.query("select * from my_table", (error, results, fields) => {
  if (error) throw error;
  console.log(results);
});
```

Comment: Thanks sir for your points. the things is I dont know where to use await in con.query() because I dont see any callbacks but consol.log(err).

and after using pool connections I`m facing the ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR.

Comment: I wasnt allowed to share my code as a comment so I put it as a new answer if you may check below....>>>

Answer (score 0):

```
const mysql = require('mysql');

const con  = mysql.createPool({
    host: "localhost",
    user: "user",
    password: "password",
    database: "mydb"
});

        // create database 
        con.query('CREATE DATABASE mydb', (err) => {
            if(err) {console.log(err)};
        })
        // create table
        const table = "CREATE TABLE customers (name VARCHAR(255), address VARCHAR(255))";
        con.query(table, (err) => {
            if(err) {console.log(err)};
            })
        // add val to table
        const val1 = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES ('Company Inc', 'Highway 37')";
        con.query(val1, (err) => {
            if(err) {console.log(err)};
        })
        // log results
        con.query("SELECT * FROM customers",  (err,result)=>{
            if(err) {console.log(err)};
            console.log(result);
        })
```

Comment: If you update your code, you shouldn't create an answer but edit your question with the new code (and probably some remarks on what you changed ...)

Comment: You should place questions updates inside the question itself by using the `edit` button underneath your question